# How to make Jupyter lab recognize a file as notebook that is not .ipynb?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I added kernels for Julia and Haskell in Jupyter lab, however the filename extension for which is still `ipynb`, and I really like to distinguish them from IPython notebook.
I renamed them as `*.ijlnb` or `*.ihsnb` however Jupyter lab no longer recognizes them as notebooks but a plain text.

How to assosiate `.ijlnb` or `.ihsnb` file to Jupyter?

Comment: It seems that this is something at the server side (jupyter_server) that needs to be changed. Based on [this issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/963) It looks like it should be possible by using a custom contents manager. An example (but outdated) script for such a custom contents manager is included in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4924 and a more advanced version is here: https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/blob/4ae9263d3cb94fea9880a6b1676af81e91092399/jupytext/contentsmanager.py#L179-L186

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to open a new feature request on GitHub to make it easier (probably jupyter_server or jupyterlab repository).